# How is the preferred source chosen in the video element?

Tags: html, html5-video

In the code below:

```
    <video id="video" poster="images/poster.jpg" width="400" height="300" controls >
        <source src="movies/clip.mov" type="video/quicktime">
        <source src="movies/clip.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="movies/clip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movies/clip.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Get the <a href="movies/clip.mp4">MP4 version</a> of the video.
    </video>
```

What if the browser supports more than one of the formats I have provided? Like both `webm` and `mp4`, which one will be chosen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They run in the order of the source elements.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#loading-the-media-resource

Answer (score 1):

The `<source>` element allows you to specify alternative video files which the browser may choose from. The browser will use the first recognized format.